# history manipulation in tcsh, substitute every match

Tags: command-history, tcsh, history-expansion

I know everybody will tell me that I should switch from using `tcsh` to `bash` or something else, but hysteresis is a powerful force, so I'm not going to.    Most of the time I find `tcsh` perfectly adequate but there's one thing I can't figure out how to do in it, but is easy to do in `bash`:  globally substitute one variable for another in a history entry.    For example: suppose history says

```
1 mv dog.tex cat.tex
```

and I want to execute the command

```
mv dog.pdf cat.pdf
```

In `bash` this is easy:

```
!1:gs/tex/pdf/
```

But the global operator doesn't work in `tcsh`.    Is there something else that does?    Thanks

Comment: For me `!1:gs/pdf/tex/` transforms `mv dog.pdf cat.pdf` to `mv dog.tex cat.tex` with tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filec.

Comment: Thanks very much @Cyrus.    I have version 6.20, maybe that's the problem.     I tried to `apt upgrade` to 6.21 but `aptitute` seems to think the current version is 6.20.   Then I tried to download a `.deb` file for version 6.21, but I couldn't a download.   (I also tried to build 6.22 from scratch but failed dismally with this.)       Do you happen to know where I might find a .deb file for 6.21?

Comment: I don't know. It comes with my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.